# Magento 2 search by Chinese words is not working

Tags: magento2, search

We are developing a site with product contains multiple languages (English, Traditional Chinese and Simplified Chinese). The search function for english is working fine but it failed to search product using Chinese.

Note: We are using Magento v2.0.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do the re-index using the following command and the problem is solved.

```
magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 1):

Magento search functionality builds on top of MySql Fulltext index that has [limitation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-restrictions.html):

Ideographic languages such as Chinese and Japanese do not have word delimiters. Therefore, the FULLTEXT parser cannot determine where words begin and end in these and other such languages.

Comment: is there any workaround?

Comment: will solr solve this issue?

Comment: I test again the function and I found that the search function is working fine with chinese words. What I have done is setup the cronjob. Is the indexing is a must for the search function to work properly?